# How can I remove the " ' " characters after splitting a string into numbered elements in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, split, bioinformatics

I'm writing a code to translate DNA strains into corresponding proteins, and I've managed to split the DNA into triplets, turning them into elements of a list.

The problem is, however, since I split the string by using the s.split() command, the elements are, for example, written as 'AUC' and so on. I'm trying to have my code read a data sheet and translate the triplets according to it. I've completed this part, as well, I simply need to find a way to remove the characters from the triplets, and by that I mean I want to write for example ['AUC' , 'GCA'] as [AUC , GCA].

Thank you in advance.

```
dna = 'ATCGCGATG'

def dna_to_mrna(dna):
    mrna = ''
    for base in dna: 
        if base == 'A' or base == 'G' or base == 'C': 
            mrna = mrna + base 
        else:
            mrna = mrna + 'U' 
    return mrna
mrna = dna_to_mrna(dna)

# We split the mRNA into triplets as elements of arrays.
def mrna_to_triplets(mrna):
    triplets = ""
    tripletsnew = ""
    for base in mrna:
        len(triplets)
        if len(triplets) == 0:
            triplets += base
            tripletsnew += base
        elif 0 < len(triplets) % 3 < 3:
            triplets += base
            tripletsnew += base
        elif len(triplets) % 3 == 0 :
            triplets += base
            tripletsnew += ('-' + base)      
    return tripletsnew
tripletl = mrna_to_triplets(mrna)
tripletstr = tripletl.split('-')
print(tripletstr)
```

This is the code I used to create the mRNA string from the DNA and then to separate it. I'm still new, so I'm trying to figure out the individual segments before somehow combining them, and I'm aware of a more efficient way to split the string into list elements. However, both this method and that one result in the elements being written in ' '.

Once again, thank you all in advance.

The code I'm trying to insert the output into is:

```
def triplets_to_prot(tripletstr):
    with open( '../data/problem_1_codons.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            rows = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            lmrna = columns[0]
            prot = columns[1]
            corres = {lmrna : prot}
            translation = [corres[base] for base in tripletstr]
            print(translation)
```

Comment: The reason the `'` character is there is to signify that it is the literal `string` AUC and **not** a variable that is named AUC. If you were to `print('AUC')` you'd get `AUC` in the console without the quotation marks. Also, **where** do you want to write `['AUC' , 'GCA']` to?

Comment: This is the code I've written afterwards:

```
def triplets_to_prot(tripletstr):
    with open( '../data/problem_1_codons.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            rows = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            lmrna = columns[0]
            prot = columns[1]
            corres = {lmrna : prot}
            translation = [corres[base] for base in tripletstr]
            print(translation)
```

I'm sorry for the terrible formatting, I'm entirely new to the website and coding...

Comment: Please add this in your question and not the comments.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a dictionary from the data file and match the output from the functions above to the corresponding proteins in the dictionary. I get a KeyError: 'AUC' as a result.

Comment: Just to be clear: You're trying to dynamically generate Python source code? That's generally a bad idea; there are _occasions_ when it's legitimately called for, but they're ridiculously rare; if it is in fact what you're asking for, the right answer is almost always "go back to the drawing board, and find a design that doesn't require this".

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you mean by that...

Comment: Ok, so in your `triplets_to_prot` you're doing too many things. This line `corres = {lmrna : prot}` overrides the directory every line you're iterating over. You should define the directory **outside** of the `for loop`. In all honesty, you should generate the directory **once** in its own function and then use it when calling this `triplets_to_prot` instead of generating every time you call `triplets_to_prot`.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `dna_to_mrna` and `mrna_to_triplets` is fine. It is the `triplets_to_prot` that has some issues. I broke it up into **two** functions. One that **generates** the codon to protein dictionary and the other that **translates**  triplets to protein according to the dictionary we created. Here is what I did:

```
def protein_dict_creation(path):
    with open(path,'r') as f:
        corres = {} # Create blank dictionary
        for line in f:
            columns = line.split()
            lmrna = columns[0]
            prot = columns[1]
            corres[lmrna] = prot # Add Entry to dictionary
    return corres # return dictionary

def triplets_to_prot(tripletstr, corres):
    return [corres[base] for base in tripletstr]

if __name__ == "__main__": # Addition of the main function

    # Generate the dictionary that translates codon to protein from file path given
    protein_dict = protein_dict_creation('../data/problem_1_codons.txt')

    # This block was removed from where it was previously defined and moved here
    dna = 'ATCGCGATG'
    mrna = dna_to_mrna(dna)
    tripletl = mrna_to_triplets(mrna)
    tripletstr = tripletl.split('-')
    print(tripletstr)
    # End of block #

    # Translate triplets giving the protein dictionary and the triple string
    translation = triplets_to_prot(tripletstr, protein_dict)
    print(translation)
```

The overall code is quite similar to what you originally provided. I just fixed the issue were you were `overriding` the dictionary for every line you were iterating over. Also now, you don't have to create a codon to protein dictionary every time you want to call `triplets_to_prot`. However, if you did want to make another dictionary with a different text file, you can call the `protein_dict_create` function and save its return value into a variable like so:

```
other_protein_dict = protein_dict_creation('other/path/to/text/file')
```